# MVC 4/Entity Framework: Update record is taking 20 seconds to save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing a simple save of some changes to a database table with about 20 columns and it takes 20 seconds. Retrieving a record is almost instant. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a faster way to do this?

```
db.Entry(EmInf).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Confirm/");
```

(MVC 4 & SQL 2008 R2 | I should note that other web sites are able to update with far more data much faster BUT they're older programs and aren't using EF. Is this a performance issue with EF? I can't see why because other MVC programs I've done don't seem to have this issue.)

Update: It's a database first setup. Forgot to mention.

Here is the full method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(Em_Emergency_Info EmInf)
    {

        try
        {
            using (var db = new WINDEntities()) {


                db.Entry(EmInf).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Confirm/");
            }


        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            int rec = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
            return View(db.Em_Emergency_Info.Find(rec));
        }
    }
```

Here is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Em_Emergency_Info
{
    public int id { get; set; } //This is the primary key.
    public string Em_PIn_Key { get; set; }
    public string Em_policy_nb { get; set; }
    public string Em_Pin_nb { get; set; }
    public string Em_First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Em_Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Em_Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Em_Addr2 { get; set; }
    public string Em_City { get; set; }
    public string Em_State { get; set; }
    public string Em_Zip { get; set; }
    public string Em_Plus4 { get; set; }
    public string Em_Phone_Home { get; set; }
    public string Em_Phone_Work { get; set; }
    public string Em_Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Em_Email { get; set; }
    public string Em_Fax_Nb { get; set; }
    public string Em_Relationship { get; set; }
    public string Em_type { get; set; }
    public bool EmailOptIn { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneOptIn { get; set; }
    public bool PushOptIn { get; set; }
    public bool FaxOptIn { get; set; }
    public string Em_Mobile2 { get; set; }
    public string Em_EMail2 { get; set; }
    public string Em_Other_Info { get; set; }
    public string Em_Primary_Contact { get; set; }
    public string Em_Full_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see more code to solve this, could you provide the full code for the class you're saving and the lines of code that are involved in the saving process?

Comment: Also, what does the table look like that you're saving to? Structure, indexes, how many rows? Anything that might affect performance?

Comment: Also, what is the lifetime of the db context?

Comment: Are there any triggers involved, indexes that must be written, dependencies that must be checked, database-generated values to be read aferwards? How long does the same update take when directly executed as SQL?